# Java Assignments query

Tags: java

**CASE 1**

```
byte b = 7; // why don't I need to cast 7 to byte in this case? byte b = (byte)7;
System.out.println(b);
```

**Output:** 7

**CASE 2**

```
static void fun(byte b) {
   System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String []args) {
   fun(7); // Compiler gives error because a cast is missing here.
}
```

**Output:**
Compilation error: `method fun(byte) is not applicable for the argument (int).`

**My question is:** How come in case 1, `7` is implicitly cast to `byte` from an `int`, while in case 2 it is forcing the programmer to cast it explicitly?

`7` is still in the range of `byte`.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric literals such as `7` are treated as integers.  So normally, as in your 2nd case, you are required to cast to `byte` to pass it where a `byte` is expected.

```
fun((byte)7); // You are forced to cast here.
```

However, your first case is special, because you are using this integer literal in a variable initialization statement.  In this case, there is a rule in the JLS that allows for an implicit cast to take place.

```
byte b = 7; // special JLS rule applies, the cast is done for you automatically.
```

[JLS Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, this one looks more appropriate reason as why compiler behaves  weird.

Comment: @Deepak: I'm happy to hear you say that.  I've been a bit surprised by the voting results on this particular question. Even if the question has been marked as a duplicate, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, you are implicitly casting to String, which is what gets pumped out to the standard output.  Your function on the other hand, requires a byte, not an integer.

Comment: You also missed the point of the question I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know.  The question is "Why in case one is the cast to int implicit, when in case 2 its not?"  By pointing out that you are not in fact casting to int in case one, I think that answers the question.

Comment: The question is: why in the first case, he is not forced to write: `byte b = (byte)7;` with the cast in front of the literal `7`.  But why in the second case, he does have to.

Comment: Ah right!  My fault.  In this case I am unsure as to the answer!

Comment: Well, enjoy the upvotes, because you're still getting them :)

Comment: There is no implicit cast to `String` anywhere in their code examples.

Answer (score 1):

In `fun(7)`, `7` is an *Integer* literal.

Try this:

```
fun((byte)7); // explicit cast, compile fine
```

**Now come to your question:**

In **case 1** `byte b = 7;` and `System.out.println(b);` are in same scope. As `7` fits in a `byte` so no need for explicit casting and `println(b)` just cast the `byte` to `string` and print `7`.

But in In **case 2**, they are not in same scope. You call `fun` with `Integer` `7` from one scope where the called function in another scope is only take `byte` instead `int`. So it doesn't matter whether `7` fits in a `byte` or not, hence compiler raise error (request for explicit casting) before the program execute `System.out.println(b);`.

Comment: I think you missed the point of his question.

Comment: @sstan, I was editing my answer whereas the first line was how to remove the error first!

Answer (score 0):

By default `7` is an `int` literal. in first case :-
`byte b = 7;` we are explicitly assigning the int literal `7` to `byte b` so implicitly java handles it & assigns the corresponding value of `int 7` to `byte` which is also `7`, meaning the casting/conversion is done implicitly by java.

But in second case `fun(7);` the 7 here is `int` type by default , but your method `fun(byte)` expects `byte` as an parameter not `int`, and as java is strictly type casted it gives the error.

Comment: byte b = 132; will not compile as its not in range of byte, it needs explicit casting